# What are the ISS moments of inertia around design axes?

Tags: iss, attitude, reference-request

I'm wondering where one can find more or less up-to-date data on the inertia matrix of the ISS. A full historical dataset would be great, of course. A discussion of error margins is desirable.

Comment: Potential Google win (see page 7-14 onwards): https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/space.pdf&ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwjLu-vx-97HAhVsWtsKHSN7AxQ&usg=AFQjCNHXRL9cuZzomgXanpCjlJnR4A7BQw&sig2=9p2P2EVUaTl9ToW4O1-mPw

Comment: @ThePlanMan - thanks, that's a beginning of a great answer. Looking forward to a follow-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ThePlanMan was on the right track. The 'On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book' contains inertia tensors for each assembly step of the ISS.

- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 1](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/space.pdf), 2002
- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 1](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20I%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008
- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 2](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20II%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008

I haven't found a more recent edition than 2008.

These don't mention error margins. Since mass and dimensions are listed to 1 mm and 1 kg (and not rounded to larger values) I'd expect the error margins to be in the region of 1 kg*mm$^2$.